# Nodejs not searching for files on pubic folder for just one route

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Nodejs application where I have kept all of my static files on a public directory.

In my app.js, I am doing:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+ "/public/src"));
```

All of my templates starts and ends with:

```
<% include ./partials/header.ejs%>
   //OTHER ejs stuff
<% include ./partials/footer.ejs %>
```

In my footer I have a bunch of script files

```
<script src="src/index.js"></script>
<script src="src/auto.js"></script>
<script src="src/ship.js"></script>
```

My code was rendering just fine, until today where my url/admin route had a bunch of

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

for all of the files.

Inside of accessing the public/src folder, the admin route is trying to access

```
/admin/src/index.js
/admin/src/auto.js
/admin/src/ship.js
```

All of my other routes are working just fine. My admin route was working fine as well, and I do not remember changing anything on that route. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: You don't show us enough info to really know, but this sounds like you're using relative paths (no leading `/`) in your HTML pages and your `admin` pages have one extra layer of depth in their path so when the browser combines the path form the HTML page with your relative URL in the HTML page, it creates the wrong path with `/admin` at the start.  The usual fix (if this is the case) is to using a leading `/` on your script URLs in the HTML pages so the browser doesn't try to combine the path of the HTML page with the src URL.

Comment: The admin files are at the same level as other routes. I could not figure out the issue  so I ended up changing the `/admin` to `/adminPanel' in both backend and frontend and now it is working

Comment: When you said it was trying to access `/admin/src/index.js` and that was wrong, what URL should it have been trying to access?  Do you have a router that is taking all the `/admin` requests so the `express.static()` route never gets a chance?

Comment: I am using router so that might have been the issue

Comment: Move the `express.static()` route in front of the `/admin router and it would probably work.